# Can't get cyrus-sasl installed on RHEL7 VM

Tags: mongodb, rhel7

I have a RHEL7 vm setup and am trying to run mongodb. After installing I get:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mongodb-database-tools-100.3.0-1.x86_64 (MongoDB)
           Requires: cyrus-sasl
Error: Package: mongodb-database-tools-100.3.0-1.x86_64 (MongoDB)
           Requires: cyrus-sasl-plain
Error: Package: mongodb-database-tools-100.3.0-1.x86_64 (MongoDB)
           Requires: cyrus-sasl-gssapi
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[vagrant@rhel7 yum.repos.d]$ mongo -v
-bash: mongo: command not found
[vagrant@rhel7 yum.repos.d]$ mongod -v
-bash: mongod: command not found
[vagrant@rhel7 yum.repos.d]$ mongod
-bash: mongod: command not found
[vagrant@rhel7 yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install cyrus-sasl
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

No package cyrus-sasl available.
Error: Nothing to do
[vagrant@rhel7 yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-gssapi cyrus-sasl-plain krb5-libs libcurl net-snmp openldap openssl xz-libs
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

No package cyrus-sasl available.
No package cyrus-sasl-gssapi available.
No package cyrus-sasl-plain available.
No package net-snmp available.
Nothing to do
```

I've tried to download cyrus-sasl and manually install it but I haven't found any information on how to properly to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says:

> This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

You either haven't paid for a RHEL subscription or haven't configured your system properly for your subscription. As a result your system cannot install any packages.

Fix your system or use an OS like CentOS that doesn't require payment for operation.